# Outlook rules match on content-type

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

Running MS Outlook 2016 for Mac. My goal is to forward meeting requests (and updates) from my work exchange email to my gmail address so I they appear on my phone's calendar. I've tried adding a server-side exchange rule matching "is meeting request" but it seems our server ignores these.

I'm now looking to do client forwarding. I can't find any "is meeting request" options in the ruleset. Looking at the email source I can see calendar entries have content-type of `text/calendar`.

```
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Is there anyway I can match on the content-type in a message body? I take it the message body contains rule matches the processed email, not the raw data.

Comment: I haven't used a version on the Mac, but i think there might be some limitation to the available options that you have (mac version). In Outlook for Windows, users can create mailbox rule to based on messages "which is a meeting invitation or update". However, I don't see it from Outlook for Mac's screenshots. Maybe you can try to see if you find anything that look similar to that?

Comment: Check and see if you have access to Outlook Web Apps for your work Exchange environment and then try creating the rule there, it should be more powerful than the Outlook rules. Most likely it will be at something like https://mail.yourcompany.com/owa

Comment: @Lex From OP: "I've tried adding a server-side exchange rule matching "is meeting request" but it seems our server ignores these." The rule is there on Outlook for server-side rules but not client-side rules.

Comment: @Abraxas Unfortunately OWA won't help cuz it'll create a server side rule which as I stated is ignored by our exchange server.

Comment: Was there ever any resolution to this? I'm having the same problem: too many calendars, using Outlook for Mac, and the rule for "is meeting request" is ignored. Thanks.

Comment: @cosmosis Unfortunately not.

Comment: @JonoCoetzee Well, that's disappointing but I appreciate you getting back to me. I will likely end up manually forwarding/adding the meeting requests.